# Import a .log file into a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have some problems to import a .log file to my notebook. It works with just some text but then when I try to import the file will I get invalid syntax.

Works:

```
 file_data = """
    64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET 
    /twiki/bin/edit/Main/ouble_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariable 
    HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
    64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:19:03:58 -0800] "GET 
    /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Message_size_limit?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariable 
    HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
    206-15-133-154.dialup.ziplink.net - - [11/Mar/2004:16:33:23 -0800] "HEAD 
    /twiki/bin/view/Main/SpamAssassinDeleting HTTP/1.1" 200 0"""

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(file_data), names=[0, 'hour', 2, 3], sep=':', engine='python')

 df['hour'].value_counts()
```

However when I try to import a .log file I will get a syntax error.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/john/Desktop/data_log.log'), names=[0, 'hour', 2, 3], sep=':', engine='python')
```

How can I solve it so I can count the 10 most common hours in the .log file?

Comment: Remove last `)` from `df = pd.read_csv('/Users/john/Desktop/data_log.log')`, so need `df = pd.read_csv('/Users/john/Desktop/data_log.log', names=[0, 'hour', 2, 3], sep=':', engine='python')`

Comment: @jezreal That was bad of me but thanks. Is it a way so I could get headers to my output? Right now I get Name: hour, dtype: int64 underneath my result when I print my result. Would be nice to have hour and count as headers. df = pd.read_csv('/Users/john/Desktop/data_log.log', names=[0, 'hour', 2, 3], sep=':', engine='python') x=df['hour'].value_counts() print(x[0:10])